# Getting authentication error while trying to run my JMS-MQ program

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I used to run similar code in standalone  applications earlier but now with MQ version-8 its giving exception. 
Getting error

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013:...
Cause by 
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

I have already tried disabling CHLAUTH by giving following command

```
       :
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH (DISABLED)

  1 : ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH (DISABLED)

AMQ8005: WebSphere MQ queue manager changed.

       :
```

```
          MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

          // Config
          cf.setHostName("localhost");
          cf.setPort(1414);
          cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
          cf.setQueueManager("QM_TEST");    
          cf.setChannel("DEV.APP.SVRCONN");

          MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) 
                  cf.createQueueConnection();

          MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) 
                  connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) 
                  session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
          MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender)                        
                  session.createSender(queue);
          MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) 
                  session.createReceiver(queue);      

          long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
          JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) 
                  session.createTextMessage("Client Message "+ uniqueNumber);     

          // Start the connection
          connection.start();

          sender.send(message);
          System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

          JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
          System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

          sender.close();
          receiver.close();
          session.close();
          connection.close();
```

Even after disabling CHLAUTH as already mentioned , I am getting the exception

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM_TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:187)
    at SimplePointToPoint.main(SimplePointToPoint.java:31)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 9 more
```

Adding AMQERR01.LOG log file content

```
----- amqxfdcp.c : 868 --------------------------------------------------------
10/1/2019 23:07:44 - Process(3172.4) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(MYNEW-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.5)
AMQ6119: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred ()

EXPLANATION:
MQ detected an unexpected error when calling the operating system. The MQ error
recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 829 --------------------------------------------------------
10/1/2019 23:07:44 - Process(3172.4) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(MYNEW-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.5)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager QM_TEST.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 3172.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 868 --------------------------------------------------------
10/2/2019 00:13:25 - Process(6536.5) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(MYNEW-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.5)
AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An internal error has occurred with identifier 20806248.  This message is
issued in association with other messages.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 829 --------------------------------------------------------
10/2/2019 00:13:25 - Process(6536.5) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(MYNEW-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.5)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager QM_TEST1.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 6536.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 868 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of mq8 is the queue manager using?  To find the specific cause you will need to review the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` log file.   What user are you running the java program under,  by default I believe new mq v8 queue managers requiremq admin users to send a valid userid and password to the queue manager.

Comment: IBM Websphere MQ Version: 8.0.0.5 , I have added AMQERR01.LOG log file content in the question above above

Comment: Need to look at `AMQERR01.LOG` from the `qmgrs\QM_TEST\errors` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers.. The issue was that queue manager was expecting userid n password.. It was my personal PC where I haven't set-up the password So I set the ```SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS CHCKCLNT``` to ```NONE``` and it worked. Not sure why making it ```OPTIONAL``` was not working . Going to check that now

Comment: Making it OPTIONAL didn't work because JMS sends a user up without a password in the default case.

Comment: @MoragHughson If you don't specify a password for JMS to send then isn't the `MQCD->RemotePassword` empty?  The queue manager only builds the MQCSP structure for CONNAUTH if both `RemoteUserIdentifier` and `RemotePassword` are filled in.  There is no indication that the OP is telling the JMS client to use the MQCSP structure, so it should be working in compatibility mode.  APAR `IT11318` does mention that if you specify to use MQCSP that JMS will send a MQCSP with a empty password, and in that case it would fail, but if using compatibility it should not fail?

Comment: @MoragHughson I checked with 8.0.0.5 and using the stock JmsBrowser sample which used the `createConnection` instead of `createQueueConnection`, it does not fail against when `CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)`.  This held true if I set `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y` or not.

Comment: @MoragHughson I them modified the JmsBrowser sample to use `createQueueConnection` and saw the the same behavior.  I then added the ability to set username and password values.  Using compatibility mode if I set username and did not set password or set blank password it worked fine.  If I specified `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y` and specified a username with either no password or a blank password it them fails.

Comment: Rohit, are you using 8.0.0.5 MQ jar files as well? 
 Are you setting the java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y`?

Comment: @JoshMc No I am not using ```com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=Y```. I am using latest IBM MQ client jar ie.    ```com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar```

Comment: That is actually rather old.   The newest stable release is 9.1.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two ways you connect to MQ server as a client.

1) Below client call creates a queue connection with default user identity.

```
      public QueueConnection createQueueConnection( ) throws JMSException
```

2) Below client call creates a queue connection with default user identity.

```
    public QueueConnection createQueueConnection( String userid,String password) throws JMSException
```

Since you used the first method, looks like a default system user id was being sent to the MQ server and since you had CHCKCLNT as OPTIONAL, the Queue manager was doing a check for the right username/password pair. As a result, you were getting MQRC 2035. Hence, you were able to resolve the issue by disabling the validation the queue manager was performing by updating the value of CHCKCLNT as NONE.

Find the link for createQueueConnection method => https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory.html